# is it possible to assign different colors to different words in a tikz edge label?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For instance I have this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [->, >=stealth', shorten >= 1pt, auto, node distance = 4cm, thick, state/.style = {circle, draw, font = \sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
\node[state] (1) {1};
\node[state] (2) [right of  = 1] {2};
\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}, label={[align=center]below:unit\\cell}]
  (1) edge node [above, color = red] {A B C} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which renders an edge from 1 to 2 with "A B C" in red. But I want to render A in red, B in blue and C in green.

Comment: Your title talks about a label, but your code shows a node text. Which is it?

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so it can be copy-paste-compiled as that it much more useful than a fragment. However, why not just `{A \textcolor{blue}{B} \textcolor{green}{C}}` ?

Comment: @Alenanno my title asks about an edge label and the square brackets refer to the edge label.

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz Yes, but your code is about the node text, not its label. In either case, cfr's solution is the quickest one.

Comment: @Alenanno I don't believe so. I just updated my sample to a full example. If you render that you'll see I'm setting the edge label color (same as how above, left, etc. refers to the label position relative to the edge and not to the node). If I want to change the node color I do it when defining the node as opposed to the edge.

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz You wrote `... (1) edge node [above, color = red] {A B C} (2);` As you can see, that's a node text. I think you might be confused by the terminology. Try replacing that with `(1) edge node [above, color = red, label={label}] {A B C} (2);` and you'll see the difference. :)

Comment: @Alenanno ahhh gotcha. Thanks. Sorry, I just go started with Latex/tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch colours within the node in the usual way i.e. using `\textcolor{<colour>}{<text>}` or `\color{<colour>} <text>`. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[every node/.style={font = \sffamily\small}, label ={[align = center]below:unit\\cell}]
(0,1) edge node [left, color = red] {A \textcolor{blue}{B} \textcolor{green}{C}} (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tricolour]